# Adjective of "in a genius way"

Tags: word-request, adjectives

Is there any English adverb to represent something as being *genius*?

Something like:

> The goalkeeper avoided the goal *geniusly*.

(I know *geniusly* is not an actual word, it's just to illustrate!)

Comment: There's an adjective with a similar (but not identical) meaning, *ingenious*. It looks like it's related to *genius*, but it's actually not.  I do wonder, though, if confusion between the two has contributed to the words becoming closer in meaning over time.

Comment: @snailboat I think you will find that *genius* and *ingenious* are in fact related. They had already drifted apart when they entered English in the Renaissance, and they essentially parted company when the modern sense of *genius* arose in the 18th century.

Comment: @talles By the way, don't you mean *adverb*, not *adjective*?

Comment: @StoneyB Yup, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, because there's no adjective to build it on — *genial, -ly* has been preempted by a different meaning. You have to rewrite your sentence so you can use genius as an attributive:

> The goalie made a genius move to save the point.

By the way, we would not say *avoid* the goal, but *prevent* the goal. One *avoids* an object or action, refrains from doing something oneself, one *prevents* someone else's action.

Comment: I ended up doing just that, rephrasing to fit "genius" in the text. I decided to ask here just to make sure.

Comment: Feels kinda natural to me thinking of an adjective for *genius* because my language (portuguese) has one: *genialmente*.

Comment: @talles a classic 'false friend'!

Comment: 'Geniously' is an adverb, not an adjective. Some adjectives end in -ly (for example, friendly), but the way you use it in the sentence clearly shows it to be an adverb.

Comment: @Sydney Definitely. That's a bad habit of mine of mistakenly calling anything that *qualifies* something an "adjective".

Comment: @talles In German they have the same form, except adjectives inflect for case/number/person. The same used to be true in English, until the effete modern practice of adding *-ly* to adverbs crept in.

Answer (score 4):

A possibility that stays very close to *genius* is **ingeniously**. It implies that it was done in an clever or inventive way.

> The goalkeeper *ingeniously* avoided the goal.

---

If you want to stress skill or talent -- not just intelligence -- you could use **skillfully** or **adeptly**.

> The goalkeeper *skillfully* avoided the goal.

---

If you want something in between the two, you can use **brilliantly**, which means it was done with great intelligence or talent.

> The goalkeeper *brilliantly* avoided the goal.

---

P.S. As StoneyB said, *prevented* is better than *avoided* here.

Comment: +1 for the *brilliantly* suggestion. It reads more natural IMO.